# Catch pattern changes callback signature

Tags: swift, swift4, decodable, do-catch

I am trying to use `JSONDecoder` to decode a json response from my server using Alamofire. When I decode the response with a `guard`, it works without any issues. The side-effect of this approach is that I can't tell what the issue is when the decode actually fails.

```
guard let result: TResponseData = try? decoder.decode(TResponseData.self, from: response.data!) else {
    self.logger.error("Unable to decode the response data into a model representation.")
    return
}
```

So instead I'm wanting to use a `do { } catch { }` but I can't figure out how exactly I'm supposed to use it within the Alamofire `responseJSON` callback.

This is what I've currently got:

```
Alamofire.request(completeUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
.validate()
 .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
    self.logger.info("POST Response: \(String(describing:response.response?.statusCode))")
    switch response.result {
    case .success(_):
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom(Date.toTMDBDate)

        do {
            let _ = try decoder.decode(TResponseData.self, from: response.data!)
        } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let error) {
            self.logger.error(error.underlyingError)
            return
        }

        completion(result)
        return
    case .failure(let error):
      //....
    }
```

What I am given with this code however is a compiler error on the `.responseJSON { (response) -> Void in` line.

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(DataResponse) -> Void'.

The guard code works fine, and if I change the `try` to a `try?` or force an unwrap, it compiles - I just don't get to have my catch handle the actual error.

If I change the `catch` block so that it does not include any pattern, then the code compiles.

```
catch {
    return
}
```

This doesn't give me anything over what my `guard` was giving me. I really want to capture the error encountered with the `decode` operation. Am I using the wrong pattern? Why does using the `DecodingError.dataCorrupted` pattern seemingly change the callback signature?

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Comment: Hey, @Hamish, why don't you write this up as an answer, so Johnathon can mark it as such!

Comment: @leanne Just done that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONDecoder` can throw errors other than `DecodingError.dataCorrupted`; you need to be able to handle the case of an *arbitrary* `Error` being thrown. So, if you want to handle that error, you'll want an unconditional `catch {}` block.

You can also:

- Use `responseData` instead of `responseJSON` as you're doing your own deserialisation with `JSONDecoder`.
- Use the `unwrap()` method on Alamofire's `Result` type in order to coalesce the network error with the decoding error, if desired.

This is what that looks like:

```
Alamofire
    .request(
        completeUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters,
        encoding: encoding, headers: headers
    )
    .validate()
    .responseData { response in

        self.logger.info(
            "POST Response: \(response.response?.statusCode as Any)"
        )

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom(Date.toTMDBDate)

        do {
            let result = try decoder.decode(
                TResponseData.self, from: response.result.unwrap()
            )
            completion(result)
        } catch {
            self.logger.error(error)
        }
    }
```

Although one thing to note here is that you're not calling `completion` if the request fails; I would personally change that such that you do, and propagate the error back by having the `completion` take a `Result<TResponseData>` parameter.

In that case, you can use `Result`'s `flatMap(_:)` method rather than `unwrap()` and a `catch {}` block:

```
func doRequest(_ completion: @escaping (Result<TResponseData>) -> Void) {

    let completeURL = // ...
    let parameters =  // ...
    let encoding =    // ...
    let headers =     // ...

    Alamofire
        .request(
            completeURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters,
            encoding: encoding, headers: headers
        )
        .validate()
        .responseData { response in

            self.logger.info(
                "POST Response: \(response.response?.statusCode as Any)"
            )

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom(Date.toTMDBDate)

            // if response.result is successful data, try to decode.
            // if decoding fails, result is that error.
            // if response.result is failure, result is that error.
            let result = response.result.flatMap {
                try decoder.decode(TResponseData.self, from: $0)
            }
            .ifFailure {
                self.logger.error($0)
            }

            completion(result)
        }
}
```